# Strange Highlighting in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

Whenever I use overleaf, I constantly get stuff like this showing up[image]

Sometimes it signifies open brackets, but most of the time it does not. I have been using overleaf for years and this issue is new. Does anybody know what setting turns this behavior off?

Comment: Ask the overleaf support.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  "Overleaf" questions may not quite be on topic, so you may be better served by Overleaf (they also tend to prowl around and help out here).  That being said, what do you mean by "stuff like this", "it", and "this issue"?  (Also, blank lines are not allowed in the `align` environment.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is more related to a particular forum.

Comment: Since you not provide a code , we can only gues what is going on at your equation ... (i) In showed equation line you have one more  `) than `(`. Correct this and than see, if still get showed warning. (ii) for simple equation don't use `align` environment, better is `€quation` (iii) do you have empty line in equation? This is error.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf) I didn't see the same problem with the same code and view settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mJAJ.png It might be something related to your browser or OS combination, could you write to us at support@overleaf.com with some more details about your setup, so we can investigate further? Thanks.